# IS camel get http request from jetty

Tags: java, web-services, jetty, apache-camel, apache-karaf

my camel router :

```
<cxf:cxfEndpoint id="chdEndpoint"
    address="http://0.0.0.0:8080/chd-esb/callService"      endpointName="s:RealServerImplPort"
    serviceName="s:RealServerImplService" wsdlURL="wsdl/RealServer.wsdl"
    xmlns:s="http://server.example.com/" />

<route id="chd-webservice">
      <from uri="cxf:bean:chdEndpoint?dataFormat=MESSAGE" />
      <log message="get client call webservice!" />
    <to ref="callChdRealWebService" />
    <log message="get real webservice back" />
    </route>
```

I deploy my camel router in karaf.
I want to know if client call webservice ,the http request first to jetty and jetty put request to camel then camel use cxf call real webservice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use Apache CXF, eg the cxfEndpoint to publish the web service on the Karaf server. And when you do that Apache CXF uses the HTTP service of Apache Karaf, which is Jetty based. So in the bottom line, its Jetty that is used.

Apache Karaf has a etc/jetty.xml configuration file, where Jetty is configured.

You can find some details about the OSGi HTTP service and Jetty on the Karaf website, such as: http://karaf.apache.org/manual/latest-2.3.x/users-guide/http.html